# What is shuddha sattva according to advaita?

Tags: advaita, sattvik

What is shuddha sattva according to advaita Vedanta
What acharyas told about shuddha sattva

Answer (score 2):

*Panchadasi, Tattva viveka prakarana ,shloka 16*

> **Satva śuddhya viśuddhi bhyāṁ māyā’vidye ca te mate, māyā bimbo vaśī kṛtya tāṁ syāstarvajña īśvaraḥ**
> When it is of the nature of pure sattva (shuddha sattva) it is called Maya, 
> when the Sattva is impure (mixed with rajas and tamas)(vishuddha sattva), it is known as Avidya. The reflection of Brahman in Maya is known as Ishwara who has Maya under His control , and is Omniscient
>  *(Swami Vidyaranya,Translated by M Srinivasa Rao , K A Krishnaswamy Iyer, Vani Vilas Press)*

---

> Avidya is that portion of the primitive non-intelligent principle in which Sattva is subordinated to Rajas and Tamas. This is known as Malina Sattva, because it is impure on account of the predominance of Rajas and Tamas. It is the reflector of Jiva whereas Maya is the reflector of Isvara. **Maya is called Suddha Sattva** on account of the predominance of Sattva. 
> This world of experience is due to the force of Avidya. It is the force of Avidya that plunges us into the ocean of Samsara. Avidya operates through the mind, and the mind functions through the time, space and causation. 
> *Doctrine of Avidya (Swami Sivananda)*

Comment: Sriman what is shuddha sattva how can we tell that ishwara has shuddha sattva

Comment: (Afaik),When Avidya is the upadhi(adjunct) of Brahman, it is known as Jiva ( be it a small creature, Human or a Deva). Avidya , the causal body of any Jiva has the predominance of both  (rajas  and tamas) over sattva, hence called Malina sattva. In contrast,Maya(adjunct) of Ishwara has abundance of sattva,(shuddha sattva) and therefore possesses the quality of all-knowing ness, (cause of creation , preservation and the dissolution).

Comment: What is characteristics of suddha sattva

Comment: If Tamas is in abundance , dominating , (sattva and rajas-negligible), then it is insentient (inanimate) so cannot know itself / know others, here it only takes up  the existence aspect of existence-consciouness-bliss(sat-cit-ananda). as per my understanding of Panchadasi text(Tamasika Ahaṅkāra is the material cause , upadhana karana of jagat). When sattva quotient increases, the there is Alpa-Jnana , Alpa-Shakti for a Jiva , knows thyself and others and acts to an extent by will.

Comment: So the characteristic of the sattva quotient illuminates the consciousness aspect. ( leads to an ascend in the plane of consciousness).As Ishwaras adjunct is shudda sattva, characterstics are sarva-Jnana ,sarva-Shakti, and Sankalpa, (can control Maya by His mere will)  (In my understanding) @PashamVishnuVardhanGoud